# Bad Request Error When Access FitBit API

Tags: json, r, api, fitbit

I'm attempting to retrieve the data from my fitbit but when I use the GET() function to access JSON I'm getting a 400 Error.

Here is my code:

```
token_url = "https://api.fitbit.com/oauth2/token"
access_url = "https://api.fitbit.com/oauth2/token"
auth_url = "https://www.fitbit.com/oauth2/authorize"
key = "XXXX"
secret = "XXXX"

fbr = oauth_app("Glinski",key,secret)
fitbit = oauth_endpoint(token_url,auth_url,access_url)
token = oauth2.0_token(fitbit,fbr, scope = c("activity","heartrate"))
```

And attempting to access JSON with:

```
GET(url = "http://api.fitbit.com/1/user/-/activities/heartrate/date/2018-01-
01/today.json", config(token = token))
```

Which results in this:

```
Response [http://api.fitbit.com/1/user/-/activities/heartrate/date/2018-01-
01/today.json]
Date: 2018-01-20 22:07
Status: 400
Content-Type: application/json
Size: 122 B
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Have you tried this: https://github.com/teramonagi/fitbitr. It's listed on the Fitbit developer website.

Comment: Apparently this has been deprecated based on what I've read since FitBit doesn't want Webscraping